# Delete or insert values on 2 identical tables with the help of trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Table1

```
COL1 | COL2
 1   |   2
 1   |   2
```

Table2

```
 COL1 | COL2 | EDIT | FLAG
 1   |   2   |   N  |  0
 1   |   2   |   N  |  0
```

--Deleting from Table2
Table2

```
 COL1 | COL2 | EDIT | FLAG
 1   |   2   |   D  |  1 --Delete this row
 1   |   2   |   N  |  0
```

--Trigger executing

Table1

```
COL1 | COL2
 1   |   2  --Trigger deleting same row as in Table1
 1   |   2
```

I have 2 identical tables (except for the part that the second Table has the EDIT and FLAG columns that the trigger should use). I wanted to make a trigger that if i change the N to D in Table2 and FLAG from 0 to 1, trigger will look at EDIT see it is D and delete the row in Table2 and the same row in Table1. Or maybe i would insert values in Table2 (3,3,'I',1) the trigger would look at EDIT see insert and make an insert value (3,3) into Table1.

I was trying this some time now, I failed miserably. Any ideas how to accomplish that.

Cheers

Comment: Can we see the triggers you have already tried?

Comment: I have inserted my try.

Comment: Not really understanding the logic in your trigger, but you should not be referencing table2 in the table2 trigger. You should be referencing the inserted table only. Same would hold true on table1, but with table1 of course.

Comment: I understand that if the code is bad, it doesnt make any sense, but that example above of how the trigger is supposed to work, that should be clear to anyone, or not?

Answer (score 0):

```js
create trigger delete_trigger on table2
for update,insert as

if exists(select * from inserted where edit = 'I' and flag = 1)
begin 
insert into table1 (col1, col2) select col1,col2 from inserted
end

else if exists(select * from inserted) and exists(select * from table2 where edit = 'D' and flag = 1)
begin
delete  table 2 select * from table2 where edit = 'D' and flag = 1
delete table1 select t.* from table1 t left join table2 wt on t.id = wt.id where wt.col1 is null and wt.col2 is null --delete
end
```

This is the answer i figured it out myself. For future reference, maybe it can help others. And tip for the user SpectralGhost, if someone makes an example like the one i did above, and you dont understand it and cant write a simple example of how the code should look like or try to put someone on the right way, pls do not comment anything, it is not helpful.

Comment: If table2 already has an `('I', 1)` row and you insert a different row into it, your first `if` will still cause the *entire* table2 to be inserted into table1. I think there was something to @SpectralGhost's comment after all.

Comment: @theweeknd How would I know what to send you as I didn't understand the logic behind what you were doing? Comments are ABSOLUTELY the right place to get that kind of clarification so you know what needs to be added/tweaked in the question to make it better understood.

Comment: i edited the code, it should now only insert from the inserts

Comment: Test your trigger with `Insert into Table2
Select 1,1,'I',1
UNION
Select 2,2,'I',1
UNION
Select 1,1,'D',1`

Answer (score 0):

This trigger would work for your specifications, **but** you did not define the handling for deleting rows in Table2 and the behavior for changing values in Col1 or Col2 with `Edit=I` and `Flag=1` will lead to new inserts in Table1, you will have to decide if this is your intention or not.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_insUp_Table2] 
   ON [dbo].[Table2]
   AFTER INSERT,UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    Insert into Table1 Select i.Col1,i.Col2 
    from Inserted i
    LEFT JOIN Table1 t2 on t2.Col1=i.Col1 and t2.Col2=i.Col2
    where i.Edit='I' and i.Flag=1 and t2.Col1 IS NULL

    Delete Table1 // if you want to
    From  inserted i where Table1.Col1=i.Col1 and Table1.Col2=i.Col2 and i.Edit='D' and i.Flag=1

    Delete Table2 
    From  inserted i where Table2.Col1=i.Col1 and Table2.Col2=i.Col2 and i.Edit='D' and i.Flag=1
END
```

Comment: You are right, i edited my code so it inserts only from inserted, it should be fine now